# I m trying to use a scalar function nd want to use taht in asp.net code but i am geeting error that 'incorrect syntax near f1 ' "Function name"f

Tags: asp.net, sql

sql code

```
create function f1( @pay float)
returns float
as
begin
return(@pay*8*10)
end
```

C# code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["abc"]);


        float a;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.f1",con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pay",TextBox1.Text);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", TextBox2.Text);

        con.Open();
        a = (float)(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        TextBox2.Text = System.Convert.ToString(a);
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can't call a function directly in C#.
Try like this,

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.f1";
Int32 count = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Hope this helps you, Thank you.

Comment: Similar to like that, you can use "Select dbo.f1"

Comment: SuganR Plz explain how value which i am taking from textbox1.text in my Example "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pay",TextBox1.Text);" would reach to the function f1 as parameter.                                                           As function f1 require a parameter..

Comment: @Rahul In SQL, You create a Procedure and call your function there.
In C#, You call the Procedure and pass the Parameter.

Hope this will help You. Thank you.